# Create and persist service object in root of django app

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio

I've created a basic django app that has a custom library installed (uses Asyncio).  I need to instantiate a factory class from the library and then use it to get some service objects back to use in the app.

```
creds = load_creds('./creds.json')
async with TestFactory(creds) as factory:
    tickets = factory.get_ticket()

    results = await tickets.find_by_number('IN12345678')
    print (results.ticket_group)
```

I've only been looking at Django for the last few days.  So I'm not sure where is best to place this code.  I just need it to persist the service objects I'm generating from the factory class and make them accessible to the rest of the app for as long as the app is running i.e. scaffold once, always accessible.

From a c# perspective, I could do this during app startup and pass it down via DI.

Answer (score 0):

I use to put things like this in a special file called `monkey_patches.py` and import that in the central `urls.py` (both files in same directory):

###### monkey_paches.py

```
# needed imports
def run_monkeypatches():
    # code for patches of some other modules, libraries and so on
```

###### urls.py

```
# all other imports needed for urls 
from .monkeypatches import run_monkeypatches

urlpatterns = [
    # all the urls
]

run_monkeypatches()  # last line in urls.py
```

So this code will run after all is set up and only once.

An alternative would be inside the `settings.py` and leave objects therein. Then you can later access those objects via `django.conf.settings.my_object` from any other app module that imports `django.conf`.